# vorbeikommen - wo? oder wohin?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality

Are all of these correct?

> Kommen Sie (*wohin?*) **zu** uns **ins** Büro vorbei.
>   Kommen Sie (*wo?*) **bei** uns **im** Büro vorbei.
>   Kommen Sie (mixed: *wo?*) **bei** uns (*wohin?*) **ins** Büro vorbei.

Google seems to return results for all of these variations.

Which variant would you prefer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bei "Kommen Sie zu uns ins Büro" ist das "vorbei" falsch; das "zu" reicht.

"Kommen Sie bei uns im Büro vorbei" ist korrekt (und umgangssprachlich).

"Kommen Sie bei uns ins Büro" würde ich sagen, wenn ich einen Unterschied zwischen Räumen machen will: "Kommen Sie bei uns ins Büro, nicht bei Frau Xyz. Kommen Sie  nicht in die Werkstatt." In jedem Fall ist das "vorbei" hier falsch.

Comment: Is this sentence ungrammatical: "[Während dieser Öffnungszeiten können Sie uns sowohl telefonisch problemlos erreichen als auch **zu uns** vorbeikommen und sich individuell beraten lassen!](http://www.rmm-containerdienst.de/oeffnungszeiten.htm)"? Should it be "**bei** uns" instead?

Comment: Weil "vorbeikommen" umgangssprachlich ist und der Beispielsatz geschäftlich ist, würde ich hier "zu uns kommen" verwenden. "bei uns vorbeikommen" geht auch und ist besser als "zu uns vorbeikommen".

Comment: Zu uns ins Büro.

Answer (score 5):

The second is correct, and you have already pointed out the distinction: “vorbeikommen” demands “wo”, not “wohin”.